# How to load the modified classes which has been imported to scalate without jetty-restart?

Tags: scala, sbt, hotswap, jrebel, scalate

I am using scalate as my view templates, and sbt + jrebel. But I found if the classes imported to scalate has been modified, we have to restart jetty, or there may be complication errors.

The code is pretty simple:

webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5">
  <filter>
    <filter-name>TemplateEngineFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.fusesource.scalate.servlet.TemplateEngineFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>TemplateEngineFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

src/main/scala/test.scala

```
package test

object A {
    def a() = "AAA"
}
```

webapp/index.jade

```
- import test.A._
= a()
```

Disable jetty's auto-reload

```
class TestProject(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultWebProject(info) {
    override val scanDirectories = Nil
}
```

Then start jetty:

```
> sbt
> jetty-run
> ~prepare-webapp
```

Visit home page:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

It displays correct:

```
AAA
```

Then I modify the `test.scala` as:

```
package test

object A {
    def a() = "AAA#######"
}
```

Visit page again, correct:

```
AAA#######
```

Then modify the method name:

```
package test

object A {
    def b() = "AAA#######"
}
```

and `index.jade` invoke `b()`:

```
- import test.A._
= b()
```

Visit again, show error:

```
Server Error: We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

From this sample we don't know where is wrong, but in my another project, we can see the reason: Failed compiling index.jade, value `b()` is not found

So I have to restart jetty:

```
> jetty-restart
```

Visit again, and everything goes well.

How to fix this issue, or is there any other way to work with scalate without restarting?

---

**UPDATE**

After nearly 1 week of trying, I have to give up. I tried all the solutions I can find, but it still can't be compiled without restart.

Now, I just run sbt without jrebel, and let jetty reload the webapp when classes are modified(not monitor scalate views). For now, it takes 3 to 5 seconds, which is not too long.

Finally, thanks for @James' help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [answer](http://groups.google.com/group/scalate/msg/c15cc88fb73037ff) on the [user list](http://groups.google.com/group/scalate)

Comment: Linked answers are looked down upon, generally speaking. It depends a lot on how much we can trust the link to remain valid for years to come.

Answer (score 0):

What mode are you running in? I believe the system property scalate.mode is defaulted to production in the source (https://github.com/scalate/scalate/blob/master/scalate-core/src/main/scala/org/fusesource/scalate/TemplateEngine.scala)